# Why express session not deleting when clicking on logout?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

Please have a look on code here https://github.com/roshantak44/nodejs-blog-tutorial

Comment: Where is the error exactly ? .Its tough to figure out from your git repo.

Comment: I think it's in the middleware(redirectIfAuthenticated.js, auth.js)or in the controller(Logout.js) you can also look for database/models/user.js

Comment: I am trying to delete the session stored in the mongo, but I can't by running function in logout.js I have to delete session manually by mongo commands.